# Client CSS propertes overiding our portion of a html tabs

Tags: html, css

We are running add-on chat solutions for different websites and we also providing different styles of chat windows but the problem is their website is having some general CSS styles like they are using:

`.div{ display:none;}` 
        or like

`*{ display:none;}`

where we are affected by these CSS properties, So please any one suggest me some solution so that we never affected by the or our code will never affect them.

Comment: know about `css specificity`

Comment: It's Good to not to apply these in general tags which affect all the codes.

Comment: Actually, we are not using those things our clients are using and we can't restrict them.

Answer (score 0):

Place `!important` to your lines. This might be a temporary solution.

Comment: no, i can't use any thing !important because it will affect their tags  and I don't have access to their HTML file

Answer (score 0):

use something like this

```
visibility:visible;
```

if you want to hide the portion you can use

```
visibility:hidden;
```

Comment: That display: none is just examples, but I am asking about general solution for all the properties of all the tags in HTML, it may be display, size, position etc

Comment: still you can hide thier css properties using visibility property for all tags

Comment: yes sir, but I need something which helps me to reset all the properties of all the tab to browser property because I can't override each and every client's chat window. because we are using one chat window for more than one clients